# Made mistake by doing independent contracting, how soon can I go back to old job?

Tags: job-change, work-life-balance, mistakes, reputation, independent-contractor

I recently left my job at Company A where I was working on separate contracts to Companies B and C. Now I'm an independent subcontractor to Company B. I left because I wanted to work less hours, work from home, and spend more time with family. When I told my old company I'm leaving, they said they would've let me work less and from home if I had asked (I assumed they'd say no given policies) and said to let them know if things don't work out.

Now I'm regretting it, I'm wasting so much time on setting this company up and I don't want to do the overhead that goes with it - invoices, contracts, finding new contracts, etc. I just wanted to make life simpler so I can spend more time with family. My first contract is for 5 months and then up for renewal. Can I return to my old job after that contract is over and say this just isn't for me? Is that too soon? Will I be seen as a flip flopper? What will that do to my reputation?

Comment: Did you ask company A if you can return?

Comment: No, but on my last day I told my managers I wasn’t sure if I was making the right decision and they said if things change to let them know.

Comment: Contact your previous manager and explain to them your situation. Sounds like they are open to hiring you back. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The whole company connection is very confusing. As long as you fulfill the contracts, there is no time you "must" stay in a job situation you don't like. Everybody makes mistakes. You will not be labelled anything if you make *one* mistake. Just make sure that your next step is the right one.

A contract that is *completed* is always a good point to consider what you want to do next. If company A is what you really want, then go for it. You could also look at other companies, maybe there are better offers.